# Entity Framework not calculating count() after grouping

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ado.net

The code will better explain what I'm trying to do.

```
var data = db.Absences//.AsExpandable()
                .Where(a => a.Employee.EmployeeCode == "Emp1" || a.Employee.EmployeeCode == "Emp2" || a.Employee.EmployeeCode == "Emp3" || a.Employee.EmployeeCode == "Emp4" )
                .Where(a=> a.Employee.Department.DepartmentCode == "HR" ||a.Employee.Department.DepartmentCode == "FIN" ||a.Employee.Department.DepartmentCode == "IT" )
                .Where(a=> a.AbsenceId > 0)
                .GroupBy(a => new
            {
                a.Employee.Department.DepartmentName,
                a.Employee.Department.DepartmentCode,
                a.Employee.IsPermanent
            })
            .Select(g => new ResultModel
                {
                    Department = g.Key.DepartmentName,
                    Permanent = g.Key.IsPermanent,
                    TotalEmployeesInDepartment = g.Select(e => e.EmployeeCode).Distinct().Count(),
                    TotalAbsenceRecordsInCategory = g.Count(),
                    TotalLateCount = g.Select(x=> x.AbsenceCode == "Late").Count(),
                    TotalSickCount = g.Select(x=> x.AbsenceCode == "Sick").Count(),
                    TotalOnSiteCount = g.Select(x => x.AbsenceCode == "OnSite").Count(),
                    LatePercent = g.Select(x => x.AbsenceCode == "Late").Count() * 100.0 / g.Count(),
                    SickPercent = g.Select(x => x.AbsenceCode == "Sick").Count() * 100.0 / g.Count(),
                    OnSitePercent = g.Select(x => x.AbsenceCode == "OnSite").Count() * 100.0 / g.Count(),
                });
```

I want total number of absences in a department, grouped by permanent vs non-permanent employees.

`TotalAbsenceRecordsInCategory = g.Count()` this is calculating fine in the generated SQL.

When I'm trying to get count of absences due to individual reasons the query is not working as expected.
`TotalLateCount = g.Select(x=> x.AbsenceCode == "Late").Count()`, this is not working, all of them are evaluated as

```
    COUNT(1) AS [A1], 
    COUNT(1) AS [A2], 
    COUNT(1) AS [A3], 
    COUNT(1) AS [A4],.. so on
```

Below are my tables

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employees]
(
    [DepartmentCode] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeCode] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeName] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [IsPermanent] [bit] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Employees] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([DepartmentCode] ASC, [EmployeeCode] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employees] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_Employees_IsPermanent] DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsPermanent]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employees] WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Employees_Departments] 
    FOREIGN KEY([DepartmentCode]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Departments] ([DepartmentCode])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employees] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Employees_Departments]
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Departments]
(
    [DepartmentCode] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [DepartmentName] [nvarchar](20) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Departments] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([DepartmentCode] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Absences]
(
    [DepartmentCode] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeCode] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [AbsenceId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AbsenceCode] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [AbsenceDate] [date] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Absences_1] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([DepartmentCode] ASC, [EmployeeCode] ASC, [AbsenceId] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Absences]  WITH CHECK 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_Absences_Employees] 
    FOREIGN KEY([DepartmentCode], [EmployeeCode]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Employees] ([DepartmentCode], [EmployeeCode])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Absences] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Absences_Employees]
GO
```

One alternative is to say

```
TotalLateCount = g.Count(x=> x.AbsenceCode == "Late")
```

but this creates nested sub queries which I'm trying to avoid.

Any idea how can I get this to work? `ResultModel` is a simple class

```
public class ResultModel
{
        public string Department { get; set; }
        public bool Permanent { get; set; }
        public int TotalAbsenceRecordsInCategory { get; set; }
        public int TotalEmployeesInDepartment { get; set; }
        public int TotalLateCount { get; set; }
        public int TotalSickCount { get; set; }
        public int TotalOnSiteCount { get; set; }
        public double LatePercent { get; set; }
        public double SickPercent { get; set; }
        public double OnSitePercent { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: In LINQ `Select` + `Count` is exactly the same as `Count`, so you need the predicate version or `Where` + `Count`. In order to avoid subqueries, you can try using conditional sum, e.g. `Sum(e => x.AbsenceCode == "Late" ? 1 : 0)`

Comment: Thanks Ivan. That `sum`  solved it for me. Also, I don't understand LINQ that well yet, however, regarding the `Select->Count()` v/s just `Count()` , I know it works same on collections however I am getting different queries in profiler for those two cases. Just reporting what I'm seeing.